# Как закрыть div при отрытии другого?

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет. не могу понять как сделать. помогите пожалуйста
Как закрыть div при отрытии другого? у меня их будет 8 штук
Вот что есть сейчас

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function f(x){
var e = x.style.display;
if( e == 'none' ){
x.style.display = 'block';  
}
else x.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<div style="height:100%; width:100%;" >

<a href="#" class="link2" onClick="f(x1);f(x2)">объект 1</a><br/>
<div id="x1" style="display:none">скрытый див 1</div>
<div id="x2" style="display:none">скрытый див 2</div>
<a href="#" class="link2" onClick="f(x3);f(x4)">объект 2</a><br/>
<div id="x3" style="display:none">скрытый див 1</div>
<div id="x4" style="display:none">скрытый див 2</div>
<a href="#" class="link2" onClick="f(x5);f(x6)">объект 3</a><br/>
<div id="x5" style="display:none">скрытый див 1</div>
<div id="x6" style="display:none">скрытый див 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: лучше не через style а классами менять, в модерновых браузерах можно тогда выбрать по классу (скажем active) убрать у него active и приделать к новому элементу, а вообще можно и через css это решить. или можно последний active запоминать в переменной, ну в общем не так как вы делаете это точно.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zz22X/

Comment: Ок, все понял, сделал, все работает. У кого есть возможность, закройте этот вопрос

Comment: я только по другому, но большое благодарствие за подсказку тебе EICTO